# undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass when creating a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm new to Rails (and to coding in general), and I can't seem to figure out what's wrong with this form.

Use case:
My site has multiple companies.  Each company can have multiple locations.  On the company show page, I need to be able to Add / Remove locations.

```
Company Model:
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :company_name, :company_website

  has_many :company_interests
  has_many :interests, through: :company_interests

  has_many :company_locations
  has_many :locations, through: :company_locations

    def add_location!(location)
        company_locations.create!(location_id: location.id)
    end

    def remove_location!(location)
        company_locations.find_by_location_id(location.id).destroy
    end

    def has_location?(location)
        company_locations.find_by_location_id(location.id)
    end
end
```

The Location Model:

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :city
  validates :city, presence: true, uniqueness: true

  has_many :company_locations
  has_many :companies, through: :company_locations 
end
```

and the CompanyLocation model:

```
class CompanyLocation < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :company_id, :location_id

  belongs_to :company
  belongs_to :location
end
```

In my Companies controller, I make all the companies and locations available in the view:

```
def show
    @company = Company.find(params[:id])
    @locations = Location.all
end
```

In the Show view, I list all the locations and show a form to Add / Remove a location:

```
<% provide(:title, @company.company_name) %> 
<div class="row">
    <aside class="span4">
        <section>
            <h1>
                <%= @company.company_name %>
            </h1>
            <p>
                <%= @company.company_website %>
            </p>
            <p>
                <%= link_to "Edit Profile", edit_company_path(@company) %>
            </p>
        </section>
        <section>
            <div>
              <h1>Associations</h1>
              <p>Locations: <%= link_to @company.locations.count, "#" %>
              <p>Interests <a href="#">7</a></p>
            </div>
        </section>
    </aside>
    <div class="span8">
        <h3>Company Locations</h3>
        <ol class="locations">
            <% @locations.each do |location| %>
            <li>
                <span class="locations">
                    <%= location.city %>
                    <div>
                        <% if @company.has_location?(location) %>

                            <%= form_for(@company.company_locations.find_by_location_id(location.id),
                                            html: { method: :delete }) do |f| %>
                            <%= f.submit "Remove", class: "btn btn-large" %>
                            <% end %>
                        <% else %>
                            <%= form_for(@company.company_locations.build(location_id: location.id)) do |f| %>
                                <div><%= f.hidden_field :location_id %></div>
                                <div><%= f.hidden_field :company_id %></div>
                                <%= f.submit "Add", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
                            <% end %>
                        <% end %>
                    </div>
                </span>
            </li>
            <% end %>
        </ol>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's the CompanyLocations controller:

```
class CompanyLocationsController < ApplicationController
    def create
    @location = Location.find(params[:company_location][:location_id])
    @company = Company.find(params[:company_location][:company_id])
    @company.add_location!(@location)
    redirect_to @company
  end

  def destroy
        @location = Location.find_by_location_id(params[:company_location][:location_id])
        #@company = Company.find(params[:company_location][:company_id])
        #@company_location = @company.company_locations.find_by_location_id(params[:company_location][:location_id])
        #@company_location = Location.find(params[:company_location][:location_id])
    #@company = Company.find(params[:company_location][:company_id])
    @company.remove_location!(location)
    redirect_to @company
  end
end
```

Adding locations works fine, but I'm getting the following error when I try to remove one:

```
NoMethodError in CompanyLocationsController#destroy
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
app/controllers/company_locations_controller.rb:10:in `destroy'
Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "_method"=>"delete",
 "authenticity_token"=>"CSeDt/aquzCyf55k4Y0Nz6O9/bwWO6gmLrd4dK/Tt08=",
 "commit"=>"Remove",
 "id"=>"1"}
```

I get the sense that there's something I don't understand about how to call the specific companylocation object in the form, but I can't figure it out.  Please help!

Comment: Just replace `params[:company_location][:location_id]` with `params[:id]` on the destroy action of your CompanyLocations Controller (shorter version: `@location = Location.find(params[:id])`

Comment: You should be using `Location.find(...)` instead of `Location.find_by_location_id(...)`. the `_by_location_id` is probably an error (it should by `find_by_id`) and the `_by_id` is implied if you call `find` with only one integer argument.

Comment: @MrYoshiji - Looks like that fixed one problem (thanks!) but now I have another - now it's telling me `undefined method `remove_location!' for nil:NilClass` in `app/controllers/company_locations_controller.rb:16:in `destroy'`. I defined that method in my Company model (posted in original q).  Any ideas?

Comment: undefined method remove_location!' for nil:NilClass` means you didn't find a company object through the id, make sure you get the proper company object first. Debug from the development log see what the sql query is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your error log, you should be able to discern what parameters you are receiving from the client, there is no params like "company_location"=>{'location_id'=> xxx } but only with a id=>1.

This is the id you get from @company.company_locations.find_by_location_id(location.id) in your form_for builder.

```
 <%= form_for(@company.company_locations.find_by_location_id(location.id),
                                        html: { method: :delete }) do |f| %>
```

So as @meagar and @MrYoshiji says all you need here is a simple `@location = Location.find params[:id]`

By the way, there are lots of redundant code in your modal, you don't need getter or setter function like

```
def add_location!(location)
    company_locations.create!(location_id: location.id)
end

def remove_location!(location)
    company_locations.find_by_location_id(location.id).destroy
end

def has_location?(location)
    company_locations.find_by_location_id(location.id)
end
```

For example, if you need to add location use this in your controller `@company.locations << @location` and Rails would take care of other things. Since you already declare the association between Company model and Location you don't need to manually write helper function to do this work.

Comment: Based on your comment, now I understand the error message - it was only passing the location ID, but the controller didn't know which company I was referring to.  I don't know the right way to do it, but I modified the form to pass both the company ID and location ID as hidden fields, and then set instance variables in the controller accordingly. I will look into eliminating the getter / setter methods. Thanks!